# How to pass an activity in BiometricPrompt object in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fingerprint-api, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

In my mobile application, I have created a separate class file to implement the BiometricManager and BiometricPrompt to use the fingerprint authentication. I have to trigger the Biometric popup in three activities, so I created a common function in separate class file. But the BiometricPrompt object has three parameters such as activity, executor & authentication callback. If I pass the Login activity object (in below code) then it is throwing an error as **"Your activity is not yet attached to the Application instance. You can't request ViewModel before onCreate call"**. Can somebody please help to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

```
NewLoginActivity newLoginActivity = new NewLoginActivity();
BiometricManager biometricManager = BiometricManager.from(context);
switch (biometricManager.canAuthenticate(BIOMETRIC_STRONG | DEVICE_CREDENTIAL)) {
    case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS:
        Log.d("MY_APP_TAG", "App can authenticate using biometrics.");
        break;
    case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NO_HARDWARE:
        Log.e("MY_APP_TAG", "No biometric features available on this device.");
        break;
    case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE:
        Log.e("MY_APP_TAG", "Biometric features are currently unavailable.");
        break;
    case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NONE_ENROLLED:
        // Prompts the user to create credentials that your app accepts.
        final Intent enrollIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_BIOMETRIC_ENROLL);
        enrollIntent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_BIOMETRIC_AUTHENTICATORS_ALLOWED,
                BIOMETRIC_STRONG | DEVICE_CREDENTIAL);
        startActivityForResult(enrollIntent, REQUEST_CODE);
        break;
}

executor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context);
biometricPrompt = new BiometricPrompt(newLoginActivity,
        executor, new BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationError(int errorCode,
                                      @NonNull CharSequence errString) {
        super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Authentication error: " + errString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(
            @NonNull BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult result) {
        super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Authentication succeeded!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        authErrorStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        login();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailed() {
        super.onAuthenticationFailed();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Authentication failed",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
});

promptInfo = new BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
        .setTitle("Biometric login for my app")
        .setSubtitle("Log in using your biometric credential")
        .setNegativeButtonText("Use account password")
        .build();
```

Please check the below log error I got in logcat.

```
2021-05-11 12:21:21.245 6808-6808/com.purchasingpower.ppow E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.purchasingpower.ppow, PID: 6808
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Your activity is not yet attached to the Application instance. You can't request ViewModel before onCreate call.
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.getViewModelStore(ComponentActivity.java:263)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.<init>(ViewModelProvider.java:99)
        at androidx.biometric.BiometricPrompt.getViewModel(BiometricPrompt.java:1027)
        at androidx.biometric.BiometricPrompt.<init>(BiometricPrompt.java:844)
        at com.app.purchasingpower.utility.BiometricHandler.checkBiometricSensor(BiometricHandler.java:109)
        at com.app.purchasingpower.activity.NewLoginActivity.checkFingerprintSensor(NewLoginActivity.java:861)
        at com.app.purchasingpower.activity.NewLoginActivity.access$2900(NewLoginActivity.java:92)
        at com.app.purchasingpower.activity.NewLoginActivity$6.onCallback(NewLoginActivity.java:802)
        at com.app.purchasingpower.activity.NewLoginActivity$1.onCallback(NewLoginActivity.java:324)
        at com.app.purchasingpower.volley.JsonObjectResponseController$1$1.onResponse(JsonObjectResponseController.java:131)
        at com.app.purchasingpower.volley.JsonObjectResponseController$1$1.onResponse(JsonObjectResponseController.java:127)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:83)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:106)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
2021-05-11 12:21:21.282 6808-6808/com.purchasingpower.ppow I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 6808 SIG: 9
```

Comment: `NewLoginActivity newLoginActivity = new NewLoginActivity();` -- **never** create an instance of an activity yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating an instance of an `Activity` yourself:

```java
NewLoginActivity newLoginActivity = new NewLoginActivity();
```

You should never, ever create an `Activity` instance in Android.  The system will always create it for you.

The solution depends where this code is: if it's in a `FragmentActivity` subclass, just pass `this`.  If it's in a `Fragment`, pass `getActivity()`.  And if it's in another class, you'll need to pass the `FragmentActivity` as a parameter over to that class so that you can pass it to `BiometricPrompt`.